# How to create .vcxitems in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, opengl-es-2.0

I created a `cross-platform` solution of **OpenGL** **ES2** Application (`Android`, `iOS`, `Windows` Universal) in **Visual Studio 2015** and noticed that there was a shared library whose file extension was `.vcxitems` instead of `.vcxproj`.

I need to create more shared libraries shared among those platforms like that. Does anyone know how to create `.vcxitems` in `Visual Studio 2015`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.vcxitems` are called Shared Items Projects.  These pseudo-"projects" contain files, but they don't actually build anything.  Instead, other projects in the solution can reference them, and thereby automatically pick up all those files.  `.vcxitems` projects are created by right-clicking on the solution name in Solution Explorer and choosing `Add` > `New Project` > `General` > `Shared Items Project`.

This is useful when you are building multiple versions of a library or program, so you have multiple projects, but they share most of their files.  You add a reference of the Shared Items Project into a real project by right-clicking on the real project name in Solution Explorer and choosing `Add` > `Reference` > `Shared Items`.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes Property Sheets and Shared Items Projects are the magic to have fun with visual studio. Then you can setup reusable libraries that are as easy to use as cmake projects.

Comment: It's good to know, I just discovered them by accident. I'm not sure exaclty how they are supposed to be used, though. As there is no build configuration they naturally don't have any understanding of additional include directories (which may differ between referencing projects) an #include <some3rdPartyLibFile.h> will always appear invalid in the editor and thus highlighted via Intellisense. Also, right-click -> Open File will never work. This makes them cumbersome to use, imo. I wonder if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @iko79 I find this: To ensure that Visual Studio intellisense works correctly with a shared project or shared library it is IMPORTANT to add a "Reference" from your standard Arduino project(s) to this library. To this by right clicking the project, click "Add Reference". When the Add Reference window opens click "Shared Projects" and you will see your shared project in the list. Check it and click OK.